# Database design - two foreign keys but one is always null and the other is always not null

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have three tables: `property`, `person`, and `company`. One property can only belong to either a person or a company. A person or a company can have more than one property.
My current database design is to include two foreign keys - `person_id` and `company_id` in `property` table, always with one of them null and the other not null. I'm just wondering is there any better way to design the database in this scenario?

```sql
CREATE TABLE person(
   person_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE company(
   company_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE property(
   property_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(255),
   person_id REFERENCES person,
   company_id REFERENCES company
);
```

Comment: I would be tempted to say that all properties are owned by organisations. Some of those organisations might be individuals.

Comment: @Strawberry This might not be a good design tho. If you do that you'll assume that company and person have the same attributes, but in the real scenario they don't. Another scenario that your design fits in could be: If the two tables are, for example, student and teacher, you can simply create a person table and add a person_type attribute to specify if a person is a student or a teacher.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: No. That's not quite it. In this scenario, users are members of organisations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create additional table CHECK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE property(
   property_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(255),
   person_id REFERENCES person,
   company_id REFERENCES company,
   CHECK (person_id IS NULL + company_id IS NULL = 1)
);
```

This will forbid wrong values (both NULL or both NOT NULL).

PS. Two references presence is legal and safe itself.

Comment: last line for PostgreSQL syntax:
CHECK (person_id IS NULL AND company_id IS NOT NULL OR person_id IS NOT NULL AND company_id IS NULL = TRUE)